# update data to additional association attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many

I have rails models like:

```
Class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :invoicepayements
    has_many :payements, through: :invoicepayements
end

Class Payement < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :invoicepayements
    has_many :invoices, through: :invoicepayements
end

class InvoicePayement < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :payement
    belongs_to :invoice
end
```

the 3 models have the following attributes:

```
Invoice: total
Payement: total, remain
InvoicePayement: used
```

in my app the `@payement` is created first and after that i create the `@invoice` with multi-select to Payement, when a new payement is created remain is equal to total (entered by user) and when a new Invoice is created i want it to calculate the value of remain from associated payement and store the used value in used attr from InvoicePayement. If rails allow me to do that? and if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found where was my mistake, i tried to apply the principle of (Fat models, skinny controllers) i created an Invoice method to calculate the remain in payement and used in InvoicePayement and it doesn't work, i decided to do things in the create controller here the code:

```
respond_to do |format|
        if @invoice.save
          total = @invoice.total
          @invoice.payements.each do |payement|
            if (total > 0) && (payement.remain > 0)
              if payement.remain >= total
                invoicepayement = payement.invoicepayements.new(used: total, invoice_id: @invoice.id, payement_id: payement.id)
                invoicepayement.save
                payement.remain = payement.remain - total
                total = 0
                payement.save
              elsif payement.remain < total
                total = total - payement.remain
                invoicepayement = payement.invoicepayements.new(used: payement.remain, invoice_id: @invoice.id, payement_id: payement.id)
                invoicepayement.save
                payement.remain = 0
                payement.save
              end
            end
          end
          format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Receipt was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invoice }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
  end
```

but now i want to improve performance, any suggestion the way i should use transactions with this code?